# Какова цель __slots__ в Python?

Tags: python, ооп

Какова цель `__slots__` в Python. Особенно в отношении того, когда его использовать, а когда нет?

<sub>перевод вопроса [Usage of __slots__?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/472000/14227417) от участника [@Jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31830/jeb)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/472000/14227417

Comment: Документация: [datamodel.__slots__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Какова цель `__slots__` в Python. Особенно в отношении того, когда его использовать, а когда нет?

### TLDR:

Специальный атрибут `__slots__` позволяет вам явно указать, какие атрибуты экземпляра вы ожидаете от экземпляров вашего объекта, с ожидаемыми результатами:

1. **быстрый доступ** к атрибутам.
2. **экономия памяти**.

Место экономится потому что

1. Ссылки сохраняются на значение слотов а не в `__dict__`
2. Запрещение создания `__dict__` и `__weakref__`, если родительские классы запрещают их, и вы объявляете `__slots__`.

#### Краткие предупреждения

В дереве наследования объявлять определённый слот надо лишь один раз

Например:

```
class Base:
    __slots__ = 'foo', 'bar'

class Right(Base):
    __slots__ = 'baz',
    
class Wrong(Base):
    __slots__ = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' # избыточные foo и bar
```

Python не возражает, когда вы ошибаетесь (вероятно должен), иначе проблемы могут не проявиться, но ваши объекты будут занимать больше места, чем должны.

Python 3.8:

```
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> getsizeof(Right()), getsizeof(Wrong())
(56, 72)
```

Это происходит потому, что дескриптор слота `Base` имеет слот, отдельный от `Wrong`.

```
>>> w = Wrong()
>>> w.foo = 'foo'
>>> Base.foo.__get__(w)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: foo
>>> Wrong.foo.__get__(w)
'foo'
```

Самое большое предостережение касается множественного наследования - несколько «родительских классов с непустыми слотами» не могут быть объединены.

Чтобы обойти это ограничение, следуйте рекомендациям:
Вычлените все абстракции родителей, кроме одного или всех, от которых будет унаследован их конкретный класс, и ваш новый класс - предоставив абстракциям пустые слоты(точно так же, как абстрактные базовые классы в стандартной библиотеке)

См. Пример ниже в разделе о множественном наследовании.

**Требования:**

1. Чтобы атрибуты, названные в `__slots__`, хранились в слотах а не в `__dict__`, класс должен наследовать от `object`.
2. Чтобы предотвратить создание `__dict__`, вы должны наследовать от `object`w, и все классы в наследовании должны объявлять `__slots__`, и ни один из них не может иметь запись `__dict__`.

Если вы хотите продолжить чтение, есть ещё много деталей.

#### Зачем использовать `__slots__`: более быстрый доступ к атрибутам.

Создатель Python, Guido van Rossum, [утверждает](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html), что на самом деле он создал `__slots__` для более быстрого доступа к атрибутам.

Продемонстрировать более быстрый доступ - это тривиальная задача:

```
import timeit

class Foo(object): __slots__ = 'foo',

class Bar(object): pass

slotted = Foo()
not_slotted = Bar()

def get_set_delete_fn(obj):
    def get_set_delete():
        obj.foo = 'foo'
        obj.foo
        del obj.foo
    return get_set_delete
```

и

```
>>> min(timeit.repeat(get_set_delete_fn(slotted)))
0.2846834529991611
>>> min(timeit.repeat(get_set_delete_fn(not_slotted)))
0.3664822799983085
```

В Python 3.5 на Ubuntu доступ с использованием слотов почти на 30% быстрее.

```
>>> 0.3664822799983085 / 0.2846834529991611
1.2873325658284342
```

Я измерил это В Python 2 в Windows получилось что примерно на 15% быстрее.

#### Зачем использовать `__slots__`: экономия памяти

Другая цель `__slots__` - уменьшить объем в памяти, которое занимает каждый экземпляр объекта.

[В моем собственном вкладе в документацию четко указаны причины этого](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots)

> Пространство, сэкономленное при использовании `__dict__`, может быть значительным.

[SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/changelog/migration_10.html#significant-improvements-in-structural-memory-use) значительную экономию памяти приписывает `__slots__`.

Чтобы проверить это, используя дистрибутив Anaconda для Python 2.7 в Ubuntu Linux с guppy.hpy (он же heapy) и `sys.getsizeof`, размер экземпляра класса без объявленного `__slots__` и ничего другого составляет 64 байта. Это не включает `__dict__`. Еще раз спасибо Python за ленивую оценку, `__dict__`, по-видимому, не вызывается до тех пор, пока на него не будет ссылаться, но классы без данных обычно бесполезны. При вызове атрибут `__dict__` имеет дополнительно минимум 280 байтов.

Напротив, экземпляр класса с `__slots__`, объявленным как `()` (без данных), составляет всего 16 байтов, и всего 56 байтов с одним элементом в слотах, 64 с двумя.

Для 64-битного Python я проиллюстрирую потребление памяти в байтах в Python 2.7 и 3.6 для `__slots__` и `__dict__` (слоты не определены) для каждой точки, где dict увеличивается в 3.6 (кроме атрибутов 0, 1 и 2):

```
           Python 2.7             Python 3.6
    attrs  __slots__  __dict__*   __slots__  __dict__* | *(слоты не определены)
    none   16         56 + 272†   16         56 + 112† | †если __dict__ упоминается
    one    48         56 + 272    48         56 + 112
    two    56         56 + 272    56         56 + 112
    six    88         56 + 1040   88         56 + 152
    11     128        56 + 1040   128        56 + 240
    22     216        56 + 3344   216        56 + 408     
    43     384        56 + 3344   384        56 + 752
```

Итак, несмотря на меньшие `__dict__` в Python 3, мы видим, насколько хорошо `__slots__` масштабируется для экземпляров, чтобы сэкономить нам память, и это основная причина, по которой нужно использовать `__slots__`.

Просто для полноты моих заметок обратите внимание, что существует единовременная стоимость одного слота в пространстве имен класса в 64 байта в Python 2 и 72 байта в Python 3, потому что слоты используют дескрипторы данных, такие как свойства, называемые «членами».

```
>>> Foo.foo
<member 'foo' of 'Foo' objects>
>>> type(Foo.foo)
<class 'member_descriptor'>
>>> getsizeof(Foo.foo)
72
```

Демонстрация `__slots__`:
Чтобы запретить создание `__dict__`, вы должны создать подкласс объекта:

```
class Base(object):
     __slots__ = ()
```

теперь же

```
>>> b = Base()
>>> b.a = 'a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    b.a = 'a'
AttributeError: 'Base' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Или создайте подкласс другого класса, который определяет `__slots__`

```
class Child(Base):
    __slots__ = ('a',)
```

И теперь:

```
c = Child()
c.a = 'a'
```

но:

```
>>> c.b = 'b'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
    c.b = 'b'
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Чтобы разрешить создание `__dict__` при создании подкласса для объектов со слотами, просто добавьте `__dict__` к `__slots__` (обратите внимание, что слоты упорядочены, и вы не должны повторять слоты, которые уже находятся в родительских классах):

```
class SlottedWithDict(Child): 
    __slots__ = ('__dict__', 'b')

swd = SlottedWithDict()
swd.a = 'a'
swd.b = 'b'
swd.c = 'c'
```

и

```
>>> swd.__dict__
{'c': 'c'}
```

Или вам даже не нужно объявлять `__slots__` в своем подклассе, и вы по-прежнему будете использовать слоты от родителей, но не ограничивать создание `__dict__`:

```
class NoSlots(Child): pass
ns = NoSlots()
ns.a = 'a'
ns.b = 'b'
```

и:

```
>>> ns.__dict__
{'b': 'b'}
```

Однако `__slots__` может вызвать проблемы при множественном наследовании.

```
class BaseA(object): 
    __slots__ = ('a',)

class BaseB(object): 
    __slots__ = ('b',)
```

Создание дочернего класса от родителей с обоими непустыми слотами не удается:

```
>>> class Child(BaseA, BaseB): __slots__ = ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#68>", line 1, in <module>
    class Child(BaseA, BaseB): __slots__ = ()
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

Если вы столкнетесь с этой проблемой, вы можете просто удалить `__slots__` у родителей или, если вы контролируете родителей, дать им пустые слоты или выполнить рефакторинг для абстракций:

```
from abc import ABC

class AbstractA(ABC):
    __slots__ = ()

class BaseA(AbstractA): 
    __slots__ = ('a',)

class AbstractB(ABC):
    __slots__ = ()

class BaseB(AbstractB): 
    __slots__ = ('b',)

class Child(AbstractA, AbstractB): 
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')

c = Child() # Нет ошибок
```

Добавьте `'__dict__'` к `__slots__` чтобы получить динамическое назначение:

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = 'bar', 'baz', '__dict__'
```

и сейчас

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.boink = 'boink'
```

Таким образом, с `'__dict__'` в слотах мы теряем некоторые преимущества размера с преимуществом наличия динамического назначения и по-прежнему наличия слотов для имен, которые мы ожидаем

Когда вы наследуете объект, который не имеет слотов, вы получаете такую же семантику, когда используете `__slots__` - имена, которые находятся в `__slots__`, указывают на значения, размещенные в слотах, тогда как любые другие значения помещаются в `__dict__` экземпляра.

Избегать `__slots__`, потому что вы хотите иметь возможность добавлять атрибуты на лету, на самом деле не является хорошей причиной - просто добавьте `'__dict__'` в свой `__slots__`, если это необходимо.

Вы можете точно так же явно добавить `__weakref__` в `__slots__`, если вам нужна эта функция.

#### Установите пустой кортеж при создании подкласса именованного кортежа:

Встроенная класс `namedtuple` создает очень легкие неизменяемые экземпляры (по сути, размер кортежей), но чтобы получить преимущества, вам нужно сделать это самостоятельно, если вы подклассифицируете их:

```
from collections import namedtuple
class MyNT(namedtuple('MyNT', 'bar baz')):
    """MyNT is an immutable and lightweight object"""
    __slots__ = ()
```

использование

```
>>> nt = MyNT('bar', 'baz')
>>> nt.bar
'bar'
>>> nt.baz
'baz'
```

А попытка назначить неожиданный атрибут вызывает ошибку `AttributeError`, потому что мы предотвратили создание `__dict__`:

```
>>> nt.quux = 'quux'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyNT' object has no attribute 'quux'
```

Вы можете разрешить создание `__dict__`, отключив `__slots__ = ()`, но вы не можете использовать непустые `__slots__` с подтипами кортежа.

## Важнейшее предостережение: множественное наследование

Даже если непустые слоты одинаковы для нескольких родителей, их нельзя использовать вместе:

```
class Foo(object): 
    __slots__ = 'foo', 'bar'
class Bar(object):
    __slots__ = 'foo', 'bar' # увы, будет работать, если пусто, т.е. ()

>>> class Baz(Foo, Bar): pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

Использование пустого `__slots__` в родительском элементе, по-видимому, обеспечивает максимальную гибкость, **позволяя дочернему элементу выбирать, предотвращать или разрешать** (добавляя `'__dict__'` для получения динамического назначения, см. Раздел выше) **создание `__dict__`:**

```
class Foo(object): __slots__ = ()
class Bar(object): __slots__ = ()
class Baz(Foo, Bar): __slots__ = ('foo', 'bar')
b = Baz()
b.foo, b.bar = 'foo', 'bar'
```

Вам не обязательно иметь слоты - поэтому, если вы добавите их и удалите позже, это не должно вызвать никаких проблем.

**Подводя итоги:** если вы составляете [миксины](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860245/mixin-vs-inheritance/27907511#27907511) или используете [абстрактные базовые классы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372042/difference-between-abstract-class-and-interface-in-python/31439126#31439126), которые не предназначены для создания экземпляров, пустой `__slots__`  в этих родителях кажется лучшим способом гибкости для подклассов.

Чтобы продемонстрировать, сначала давайте создадим код с классом, который мы хотели бы использовать при множественном наследовании.

```
class AbstractBase:
    __slots__ = ()
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({repr(self.a)}, {repr(self.b)})'
```

Мы могли бы использовать вышесказанное непосредственно путем наследования и объявления ожидаемых слотов:

```
class Foo(AbstractBase):
    __slots__ = 'a', 'b'
```

Но нас это не волнует, это тривиальное одиночное наследование, нам нужен другой класс, от которого мы также могли бы унаследовать, возможно, с шумным атрибутом:

```
class AbstractBaseC:
    __slots__ = ()
    @property
    def c(self):
        print('getting c!')
        return self._c
    @c.setter
    def c(self, arg):
        print('setting c!')
        self._c = arg
```

Теперь, если бы на обеих базах были непустые слоты, мы не смогли бы сделать следующее. (На самом деле, если бы мы хотели, мы могли бы дать `AbstractBase` непустые слоты `a` и `b` и исключить их из приведенного ниже объявления - оставлять их было бы неправильно):

```
class Concretion(AbstractBase, AbstractBaseC):
    __slots__ = 'a b _c'.split()
```

И теперь у нас есть функциональность от обоих через множественное наследование, и мы все еще можем запретить создание экземпляров `__dict__` и `__weakref__`:

```
>>> c = Concretion('a', 'b')
>>> c.c = c
setting c!
>>> c.c
getting c!
Concretion('a', 'b')
>>> c.d = 'd'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Concretion' object has no attribute 'd'
```

### Другие случаи, чтобы избежать слотов:

- Избегайте их, если вы хотите выполнить назначение `__class__` с другим классом, у которого их нет (и вы не можете их добавить), если макеты слотов не идентичны. (Мне очень интересно узнать, кто это делает и почему.)
- Избегайте их, если вы хотите создать подкласс встроенных функций переменной длины, таких как `long`, `tuple` или `str`, и хотите добавить к ним атрибуты.
- Избегайте их, если вы настаиваете на предоставлении значений по умолчанию через атрибуты класса для переменных экземпляра.

Возможно, вам удастся выявить дополнительные предостережения из остальной части [документации `__slots__` (наиболее актуальной является документация разработчика версии 3.7)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#slots), в которую я недавно внес значительный вклад.

<sub>перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28059785/14227417) от участника [@AaronHall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541136/aaron-hall)</sub>