# Как правильно и грамотно писать на питоне? (best practice)

Tags: python

Всем привет, вопрос по поводу того, какие решения лучше применять в написании кода на python. До этого два года изучал джаву, сейчас изучаю питон по Лутцу и появились некоторые вопросы по тому, какие инструменты и подходы лучше использовать в определенных ситуациях.Так как питон довольно гибок, хотелось бы узнать, какие ВЫ используете приемы в случаях:

1. геттеры и сеттеры. Нужны ли они вообще в питоне с его слабой поддержкой инкапсуляции данных и если нужны, как лучше их реализовывать - через @property или через класс дескриптор?
2. Использование ****slots****. Использовали ли их вы когда нибудь в своей повседневной работе?
3. Реализация приватных полей - нужны ли они в данном языке, если нужны, как их лучше реализовать?

Спасибо за ответы

Comment: отлиичный ответ про [slots](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206730/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-slots-%d0%b2-python). Тожк уходил с java на python. Острой необходимости добавлять все геттеры и сеттеры как в java я не нашел. Добавляю, только когда нужно. Приватные поля не похожи на java, но определить их можно с двойным нижним подчеркиванием. Как таковые приватные поля на python могут быть прочитаны и изменены. Редко пользуюсь, но бывает. Мнение субъективно)