# объясните, пожалуйста, код из книги для начинающих

Tags: python, классы

Изучаю сейчас Пайтон, увидела вот такое упр, где нужно понять, что произойдет

```
import copy
class Car:
    pass

car1 = Car()
car1.wheels = 4
car2 = car1
car2.wheels = 3
print(car1.wheels)  

car3 = copy.copy(car1)
car3.wheels = 6
print(car1.wheels)
```

сначала я вообще думала, что будет ошибка, ибо в классе Car не определена функция  wheels, не понимаю что это такое

вот эта часть тоже не особо понятна, почему выводится 3, а не 4?

```
car1 = Car()
car1.wheels = 4
car2 = car1
car2.wheels = 3
print(car1.wheels)
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: `car2 = car1` - объект в car1 и car2 один и тот же. Присваивание не сделает копию

Comment: Насчет `wheels`, это не функция, а поле. И так устроены классы в питоне, что можно любой атрибут добавлять, если не указывать в классе `__slots__`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206730/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-slots-%D0%B2-python

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

```
import copy

class Car:
    pass
```

Подключена библиотека `copy`, описан "пустой" класс `Car`, у которого ничего нет внутри - ни методов, ни полей.

```
car1 = Car()
car1.wheels = 4
```

Создали новый объект класса `Car`, сделали ему новое поле `wheels` и положили туда значение. Питон - язык динамический, объектам можно "на ходу" добавлять всякие штуки, например, поля (переменные класса).

```
car2 = car1
car2.wheels = 3
print(car1.wheels)
```

`car2` - **ссылка** на объект `car1`, всё, что делается с `car2`, на самом деле делается с `car1`, поэтому в `car1.wheels` будет тоже самое, что в `car2.wheels`.

```
car3 = copy.copy(car1)
car3.wheels = 6
print(car1.wheels)
```

А вот тут `car3` - это **копия** объекта `car1`, поэтому всё, что делается с объектом `car3` уже никак не влияет на объект `car1`. При копировании объекта новому объекту в момент копирования достаются значения полей старого объекта, но дальше этот новый объект и его поля живут уже своей отдельной жизнью.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Цель этого кода: Показать вам, что для объектов вообще *простое присваивание не создает новый объект* — результатом будет только **другое имя для того же самого объекта:**

```
car1 = Car()               # Создание нового объекта с именем car1
car1.wheels = 4            # Создание атрибута wheels для него, со значением 4
car2 = car1                # Новое ИМЯ для ТОГО-ЖЕ объекта
car2.wheels = 3            # Изменение атрибута того-же объекта из 4 на 3
print(car1.wheels)         # Проверка того, что объект car1 тот же самый, как объект car2
```

Другими словами, не надо удивляться над тем, что вы изменили значение атрибута объекта `car2` на 3, а тем самым изменился атрибут объекта `car1` на 3: `car2`не другой объект, это только другое имя для `car1`.

---

Остальной код показывает, как создать **новый объект** как копию существующего:

```
car3 = copy.copy(car1)
```

и проверка того, что это самостоятельный объект, не зависимый от `car1`:

```
car3.wheels = 6         # Изменим значение атрибута wheels объекта car3 на 6 ...
print(car1.wheels)      # ... но атрибут wheels объекта car1 не изменится (остается 3)
```

В результате:

- `car1`, `car2`: первый объект (с 2 именами),
- `car3`: второй объект.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!))

Comment: @bibi_thth89, не стоит. :-) [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)